# Coupon for fixed total cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to set up a coupon on my site so that a total price of cart will be 79$ no matter whats in cart.

It should work only for current customers.

For example:

In my cart is: 
1x product X, 2x product Y, total 200$ but coupon should change it to 79$

10 product X, total 1000$ but coupon should change it to 79$

Total price should be always 79$

Comment: You have not asked a question. What's the problem?

Comment: How can I achieve that? ;)

Comment: Your question is off-topic for this site. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [**What topics can I ask about here?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). And perhaps the [**WooCommerce support page**](https://woocommerce.com/contact-us/).